# Huge collections in Python

Tags: python, performance, collections

Basically I am storing millions of vector3 values in a list. But right now the vector3s are defined like so:

```
[5,6,7]
```

which I believe is a list. The values will not be modified nor I need any vector3 functionality.

Is this the most performant way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are storing millions of them, the best way (both for speed and memory use) is to use [numpy](https://numpy.org/).

If you want to avoid numpy and use only built-in python modules, using tuples instead of lists will save you some overhead.

Comment: Ahem. If not using numpy, use the `array` module.

Answer (score 6):

The best way is probably using tuples rather than a list. Tuples are faster than lists, and cannot be modified once defined. http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences

edit: more specifically, probably a list of tuples would work best: [(4,3,2), (2,4,5)...]

Answer (score 4):

Traditionally, you would profile your code, find bottlenecks, and deal with them as required. The answer is "No it probably isn't *the most performant way*" but does that really matter? It might do, and when it does, it can be fixed.